# XPath - Return Null if single instance of element contains specific text

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, xmlnode, xpath-1.0

In an XML document such as:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>Text1</c>
    ...
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>Text2</c>
    ...
  </b>
  ...
</a>
```

What is a single XPath 1.0-compatible, local-namespace()-compatible, expression to return a Null set if any  element contains the inner text of 'Text1'.

I have tried numerous different expressions and cannot get elements that would return a null set.

e.g.

```
//*[local-name()='c' and .='Text1']

- or -   

/*[local-name()='a']/*[local-name()='b']/*not(local-name()='c' and .='Text1'])
```

The stringent requirements are due to a specific implementation of the .NET function call XmlNode.SelectSingleNode Method (String)

**Final exact solution**
*Courtesy Dimitre*

```
/*[not(//*[local-name()='c' and . = 'Text1'])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a single XPath 1.0-compatible, local-namespace()-compatible,
>   expression to return a Null set if any element contains the inner text
>   of 'Text1'.

You haven't specified what should be selected if there is no such `c` element, so below I select in this case the top element.

**Use**:

```
/*[not(//c[. = 'Text1'])]
```

This would select nothing in case there is a `c` element in the XML document, whose string value is "Text1".

**In case of using default namespace, this would be written as**:

```
/*[not(//*[name()='c' and . = 'Text1'])]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*[not(//c[. = 'Text1'])]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>Text1</c>
    ...
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>Text2</c>
    ...
  </b>
  ...
</a>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output -- in this case nothing is produced -- as expected**.

**If we change the above XML document to**:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>Text3</c>
    ...
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>Text2</c>
    ...
  </b>
  ...
</a>
```

**then the condition is `true()` and the result of the evaluation is the subtree rooted by the top element**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>Text3</c>
    ...
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>Text2</c>
    ...
    </b>
  ...
</a>
```

Comment: I have a feeling this is what I am looking for (though, using local-name() instead of name()), but I keep getting an invalid token error. Thoughts?

Comment: @Jonathan, The solution *is* correct -- I will publish an XSLT - based verification in a few minutes. Everyone can run this and see that the correct result is produced.

Comment: @Jonathan, Done. You may run the transformation yourself and see that the XPath expression has the wanted result(s).

Comment: @Dmitre, The logic is correct, but the name() function does not take into account some rather limited namespace handling in the implementation. However, changing name() to local-name() in fact worked without any other modification necessary. Cheers!

Comment: @Jonathan, You are welcome. As for namespace handling, there are no special namespaces in the provided XML document, and I didn't want to be making guesses about the real document.

Answer (score 0):

Just negate your expression

```
not(//*[local-name()='c' and .='Text1'])
```

It will return `true` if there is no `<c>Text1</c>`, otherwise, it does not return anything.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, my one concern here is that it has to return a set of elements, and cannot return a boolean.